# ANSI C warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, ansi-c

I am using ANSI C with gcc complier and getting warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type for my code.

Note: structs, typedefs and pointers are given to me. So I am not allowed to change them.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct tm * tm_type_ptr;
typedef struct stock_list * stock_list_ptr;
typedef struct coin * coin_list_ptr;

typedef struct tm {
    coin_list_ptr coins;
    stock_list_ptr stock;
} tm_type;

struct stock_data 
{
    char ticket_name[TICKET_NAME_LEN+1];
    char ticket_type;
    char ticket_zone[TICKET_ZONE_LEN+1];
    unsigned int ticket_price;
    unsigned int stock_level;
};

typedef struct stock_node 
{
    struct stock_data * data;
    struct stock_node * next_node;
} stock_node;

struct stock_list
{
    stock_node * head_stock;
    unsigned int num_stock_items;
};

enum coin_types {
    FIVE_CENTS=5,
    TEN_CENTS=10,
    TWENTY_CENTS=20,
    FIFTY_CENTS=50,
    ONE_DOLLAR=100,
    TWO_DOLLARS=200
};

struct coin {
    enum coin_types denomination;
    unsigned count;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    tm_type tm;
    tm_type *tm_ptr;
    tm_ptr = &tm;

    system_init(tm_ptr);

    return EXIST_SUCCESS;
}

system_init(tm_type * tm)
{

   struct coin clist;   
   struct coin_list_ptr * clist_ptr;

   clist_ptr = &clist;

   stock_node * snode = (stock_node *) malloc(sizeof(stock_node));

   snode->data = (struct stock_data *) malloc(sizeof(struct stock_data));

   struct stock_list * slist = (struct stock_list *) malloc(sizeof(struct stock_list));

   stock_list_ptr * slist_ptr = (stock_list_ptr *) malloc(sizeof(stock_list_ptr));

   slist->head_stock = snode;

   slist_ptr = &slist;

   tm = (tm_type *) malloc(sizeof(tm_type));

   tm->stock = slist_ptr;
   tm->coins = clist_ptr;
}
```

Comment: how about including the warning - which type is it complaining about?

Comment: @John3136 warning is included at the top of my question. there is nothing more than that. here is again:  warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Comment: Warnings give you line numbers. That's what makes them useful.

Comment: @ChrisHayes :) tm->stock = slist_ptr; this is the line it complains about. it is in the system_init()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stock_list_ptr * slist_ptr = ...` so `slist_ptr` is a pointer to a stock list pointer

`tm->stock` is just a stock list pointer.

You should also goole why casting the result of malloc is a bad idea..

Also:

```
 /* malloc memory (size = 1 pointer) and assign address to stock_list_ptr */
 stock_list_ptr * slist_ptr = (stock_list_ptr *) malloc(sizeof(stock_list_ptr));
 slist->head_stock = snode;
 /* assign address of slist to slist_ptr. So you have overwritten the assignment
    above, and leaked 1 pointer's worth of memory.
    stock_list_ptr slist_ptr = &slist; is proabably what you meant...
  */
 slist_ptr = &slist;
```

Comment: Do you mind if you give me exactly how should it be in a correct way?

Comment: Looks to me like you expect `slist_ptr` to be a `stock_list_ptr`, not a `stock_list**`, so remove the extra `*` on the declaration.

Comment: stock_list_ptr slist_ptr = (stock_list_ptr *) 
      malloc(sizeof(stock_list_ptr));

this didn't work.

should it be like below?

stock_list_ptr * slist_ptr = (stock_list_ptr) 
      malloc(sizeof(stock_list_ptr));

Comment: Just noticed: why malloc slist_ptr when you overwrite it with `&slist` a couple of lines down: aka you have a memory  leak.

Comment: Okay. Got it working in this way:

stock_list_ptr slist_ptr = (stock_list_ptr) malloc(sizeof(stock_list_ptr));

and removed & from &slist.

Thanks John

Comment: You still have a leak - you don't need the `slist_ptr = (stock_list_ptr) malloc(...` at all.

Comment: If I don't define slist_ptr then tm->stock doesn't work. Do you mean I don't need to allocate memory for it?

Comment: I have tested the program with gdb and doesn't give me any memory leak

Answer (score 0):

Number of issues

1.Missing defines

```
#define TICKET_NAME_LEN (100)
#define TICKET_ZONE_LEN (100)
#define EXIST_SUCCESS (0)
```

2.Missing return type.

```
// system_init(tm_type * tm)
void system_init(tm_type * tm)
```

3.OP is declaring a pointer to a pointer when OP wants a pointer.

```
//struct coin_list_ptr * clist_ptr;
coin_list_ptr clist_ptr;
//stock_list_ptr * slist_ptr = (stock_list_ptr *) malloc(sizeof(stock_list_ptr));
stock_list_ptr slist_ptr = malloc(sizeof(stock_list_ptr));
//slist_ptr = &slist;
slist_ptr = slist;
```

4.Suspect additional issues.

Comment: I didn't add missing defines to simplify the code however they are exist. The second one, missing type; actually it is a BOOLEAN but I made a typo when I was simplifying the code. Finally the 3rd one; I have changed it exactly same as you have recommended. However John3136 thinks there is a memory leak.